# 301 redirection through .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm using CodeIgniter.
in httacess file, I wrote this code to remove index.php from url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I want to redirect site root to subdomain, with this code:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ sub.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

domain.com redirected to sub.domain.com successfully. but domain.com/dir to sub.domain.com/dir not work and still opening domain.com/dir.
When I removed first code, redirection worked perfect, but I need to remove index.php too.

Comment: Is `dir` a real directory? Does it have .htaccess also?

Comment: No, actually its a CNAME.

Comment: How can `/dir/` be a CNAME? Your `sub.domain.com` can be a CNAME but my question is about `/dir/`?

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I means that `sub.domain.com` is a CNAME. '\dir\` is a virtual directory. I have many of these paths that created by CodeIgniter. for example `sub.domain.com/contact` and there isn't a directory with the name of `contact` in `public_html`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `$`to the end of `rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]` should fix it for you.

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ sub.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Would become

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ sub.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this change before, and I tried it again, but no difference and still not work. domain.com/dir still not redirect.

Comment: If you remove the other conditions and rules from the htaccess file, would the redirect work?

Comment: Yes, When I remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` redirect work. but this code is necessary too.

Comment: If everything is being redirected to the sub domain, couldn't you create a htaccess file in the sub domain with the other conditions and rules?

Comment: Actually its a CNAME. I created it with Cloudflare. There is no folder for subdomain.

Comment: Did you try moving the above rules to above your previous rules?

Comment: I changed the order of codes like this: `RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`. Now when Im going to `domain.com/dir`, redirect loop happened. `http://domain.com/index.php?/sub.domain.com/&/sub.domain.com/index.php&/sub.domain.com/index.php&/...`

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```